# SwiftUI ListStyle - Result values in '? :' have mismatching types

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use the same view both for iOS and macOS changing only .listStyle() since InsetGroupedListStyle() is not available on macOS.

```
@ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if subject.tasks.count == 0 {
            
            VStack {
                Text("app.main.smartList.noTasks")
                Image(systemName: "tray.fill").font(.system(size: 90)).padding(40)
            }.navigationTitle("Empty")
            
        } else {
            
                List(subject.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
                    TaskView(task: task).environmentObject(self.controller)
                }
                .listStyle(controller.currentOS == OS.iOS ? InsetGroupedListStyle() : DefaultListStyle())
                .navigationTitle(subject.name)
        }
    }
```

But I keep receiveing this error.

**Result values in '? :' espressione have mismatching types 'InsetGroupedListStyle' and 'DefaultListStyle'**

Aren't they both List Styles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both list styles, but of different concrete types, so swift type checker does not allow such, instead we can use custom modifier like

```
extension List {
    @ViewBuilder
    func insetListStyle(if flag: Bool) -> some View {
        if flag {
            self.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        } else {
            self     // implicit DefaultListStyle
        }
    }
}
```

and now use it as

```
List(subject.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
    TaskView(task: task).environmentObject(self.controller)
}
.insetListStyle(if: controller.currentOS == OS.iOS)
```