# Different List styles for macOS and iOS

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm writing multi-platform app for macOS and iOS on SwiftUI. On iOS I need to view List as DefaultListStyle() and on macOS as SidebarListStyle(). I have tried:

```
 #if os(iOS)
.listStyle(DefaultListStyle())
 #else 
.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
 #endif
```

and:

```
.listStyle(macOSCheck ? SidebarListStyle() : DefaultListStyle()) 
//macOSCheck checks if target is macOS
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65267321/12299030?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this, and unfortunately they are all a bit clumsy. Here are 3 solutions I use in practice.

### if-else in `body`

The most straightforward way is to duplicate everything in `body` for both platforms:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        #if os(iOS)
            List {
                ...
            }
            .listStyle(DefaultListStyle())
        #else
            List {
                ...
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        #endif
    }
}
```

Obviously this can lead to a lot of code duplication, but you may be able to reorganize your code to minimize it.

### typealias

For what you’re trying to do, I’d suggest defining a `typealias` somewhere in your code:

```
#if os(iOS)
typealias MyListStyle = DefaultListStyle
#else
typealias MyListStyle = SidebarListStyle
#endif
```

… which you can then use wherever you need it:

```
.listStyle(MyListStyle())
```

### ViewModifier

If you run into problems like this a lot (and if you're doing cross-platform SwiftUI, you will), then you should consider creating a view modifier that lets you execute arbitrary code, including `#if os()` checks:

```
extension View {
    func modify<T: View>(@ViewBuilder _ modifier: (Self) -> T) -> some View {
        return modifier(self)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ...
        }
        .modify {
            #if os(iOS) {
                $0.listStyle(DefaultListStyle())
            #else
                $0.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.overdesigned.net/posts/2020-09-23-swiftui-availability/) about this last approach, if you want to learn more.